# Survey Question Validation before shows up

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, survey

I have question "Choice [menu to choose form]" - Radio Buttons type. 
I want to show only those possibilities choices that was not selected by others users.

My question is how to do this, and can i do this in standard survey setup (Branching Logic, Column Validation) or I need create some SP/jQuery script?

I'm using SharePoint 2013.